# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

I have problem at my code.
This is part of `__init__`:

```
file = np.loadtxt(file_path,delimiter = ",",skiprows=1)
header = np.loadtxt(file_path,delimiter = ",",dtype=str)
self.data = file
self.header = header[0]
```

This is part of a method:

```
def hello(self,col_name)
    col = self.header.where[a == col_name]
    return col
```

Then I wanted to check if I get the index of the header:

```
print (name.hello('hi'))
```

but got: `"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'where'"`

Comment: `where` is a `numpy` function, not a `ndarray` method.  Also it does not work with `[]`. 
 Plez review it's documentation.